# Multi-Select selector is not selecting more than one item from the selector field

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to create a multi-select selector field where more than one item needs to be selected from the selector, but I am only able to select one item and when I try to select more than one the item does not show on the selector field and when saved only the first item selected is saved.

Selector List:

[Selector List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG4K9.png)

Item Selected:

[item selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYssC.png)

**DAC code snippet**

```
       [PXDBString(255)]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Module")]

       [PXSelector(

               typeof(ModulesTable.id),
                  DescriptionField = typeof(ModulesTable.description), ValidateValue = false)]
       public virtual string UsrModule { get; set; }
       public abstract class usrModule : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrModule> { }
       #endregion
```

**ASPX code snippet for the selector:**

```
  <px:PXMultiSelector runat="server" DataField="UsrModule" ID="CstPXSelector5" CommitChanges="True" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the source code change the `PXDBString` attribue from
`PXDBString(255)` to `PXDBString(255,IsUnicode = true)`.

Add the `ValuesSeparator=","` and `AllowCustomItems="True"` properties for the `PXMultiSelector` control:

```
<px:PXMultiSelector ValuesSeparator="," AllowCustomItems="True"  AutoRefresh="True"  DataSourceID="ds" runat="server" ID="edFieldID" DataField="FieldID" CommitChanges="True" />
```

Change `PXSelector` attribute by this:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<ModulesTable.id>), DescriptionField = typeof(ModulesTable.description), ValidateValue = false)]
```

Comment: I tried the method, but i still can't select more than one item.

Comment: the selector does't work if an item is selected from the selector list but if the id is typed in then item is shown on the selector textfield  but an error shows stating that the 'Module' (which is field name) does not exist.

Comment: @PlainJane Please update your question with an error message screenshot

Comment: @PlainJane I have updated the answer, please check it.